# Docker сеть между контейнерами

Tags: docker

Есть два контейнера:

```
localadmin@docker:~/start$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
b8728ae7d377        nginx/production    "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes       0.0.0.0:8083->80/tcp   web_app_mode_of_work_vrach
f1f92a15cbdc        vzr/production      "/var/www/mode_of_..."   11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes       0.0.0.0:8082->80/tcp   mode_of_work_vrach
localadmin@docker:~/start$
```

Оба находятся в сети:

```
localadmin@docker:~/start$ docker network inspect 
bridge_mode_of_work_vrach
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge_mode_of_work_vrach",
        "Id": "baaa83586665ee342433c90466d9bd20fc2b462253f43db9ac830c0e4fb93565",
        "Created": "2017-09-29T13:24:41.00948858+07:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "Containers": {
            "b8728ae7d377c63536865bae7c1d882588559dbdca8a2875b0203b695fff4037": {
                "Name": "web_app_mode_of_work_vrach",
                "EndpointID": "16fda2a933e9877443315d38c611d9f42643ebdaae4fbce320f946f087f20011",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "f1f92a15cbdc8807607051d500ca331feb5d257c12e21963d4e770dd058bc704": {
                "Name": "mode_of_work_vrach",
                "EndpointID": "6636c95002ff33e389b410a445a1a938601fb300f536ee7cbcb4a6140f928214",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
localadmin@docker:~/start$
```

С контейнера `web_app_mode_of_work_vrach` (nginx) пытаюсь сделать запрос на фронтенд:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В результате получаю ошибку.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно обращаться к другим контейнерам для выполнения запросов к ним?

```
xhr.js:178 GET http://mode_of_work_vrach/get_mode net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Добавил на сервере `web_app_mode_of_work_vrach` в `hosts`:

```
root@100bde51b056:/# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.18.0.3      100bde51b056
172.18.0.2      mode_of_work_vrach
root@100bde51b056:/#
```

`mode_of_work_vrach` стал пинговаться:

```
root@100bde51b056:/# ping mode_of_work_vrach
PING mode_of_work_vrach (172.18.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from mode_of_work_vrach (172.18.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.100 ms
64 bytes from mode_of_work_vrach (172.18.0.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.071 ms
^C
--- mode_of_work_vrach ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.071/0.085/0.100/0.017 ms
root@100bde51b056:/#
```

Но когда из контейнера из веб приложения делаю запрос на адрес `http://mode_of_work_vrach/get_mode`, получаю ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Извиняюсь, но от кода запроса под рукой остался только скриншот.

Comment: в `/etc/hosts` внутри одного контейнера присутствует упоминание имени второго?

Comment: насколько помню, драйвер bridge не предполагает резолва DNS, он находится в полуактуальном состоянии ради обратной совместимости и нужен только для доступа контейнера во внешнюю сеть. Все остальное вы делаете правильно, доступ к конечному контейнеру стоит делать через его имя в сети.

Comment: добавил в тему подробности.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас контейнер mode_of_work_vrach прокинут на порт 8082 киньте запрос на localhost:8082.

Comment: Дайте более развёрнутый  ответ.